# R ggplot: How to plot duplicate plots with different color schemes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like the following:

```
x<- runif(9, 0,10)
y<- runif(9,1,5)
z<- rep(c('a','b','c'), each=3)
df<- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
df<- cbind(df,z)
df$z<- as.factor(df$z)
```

I want to make a series of box plots where the data is the same in each plot but the points are colored according to `df$c`. So here it would be 3 plots. In the first plot, points would be blue unless `df$c== 'a'` in which case they would be red. For the second plot, the red points would have `df$c=='b'` and so on. Is there a way to do this within ggplot or tidy verse without having to encode the variables in the original data frame?

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point(aes(color=(z=='a'))` would be your first graph.

Comment: Yes however, I'm wondering how to generalize this to factors with multiple levels or to automatically make many plots similar to `facet_wrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these options. First, with the composer of plots `patchwork` and polishing the great suggestion from **@PeterK**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
#Code
G1 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(aes(color=(z=='a')))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','red'))+
  ggtitle('a')+
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
G2 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(aes(color=(z=='b')))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','red'))+
  ggtitle('b')+
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
G3 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(aes(color=(z=='c')))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','red'))+
  ggtitle('c')+
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
#Assemble
GF <- wrap_plots(list(G1,G2,G3),nrow = 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Or using facets:

```
#Code 2
df %>% mutate(VarA=ifelse(z=='a','keep','all'),
              VarB=ifelse(z=='b','keep','all'),
              VarC=ifelse(z=='c','keep','all')) %>%
  select(-z) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(x,y)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,color=value))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','red'))+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free')+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]